# How can I offset the pointer on a JSilder?

Tags: java, offset, jslider

In Java how can I offset the knob from my JSilder track?

```
                \/
|------------------------------|
```

I want it above the track, not on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to create a custom SliderUI.

You would probably extend MetalSliderUI. The paintThumb() method is responsible for painting the thumb so you probably need to customize that method to change the Y offset of the thumb. You would then also need to change the preferred size calculation to account for this offset as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean, how can you set the current value of the JSlider, you should read the [API](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JSlider.html#setValue(int)) and see that you can use setValue.  The question sounds confusing because you use the terms pointer and offset, which typically carry a completely different meaning in programming.

Comment: I do not mean current value. I mean, how can I move the pointer away from the bar so its not on top.

Comment: In that case, I think you want setExtent.